# Java - JDBC Works in Eclipse Not CL

Tags: java, jdbc

So, the code below works in Eclipse but it doesn't work in CL.  I'm thinking it has to do with the JDBC connector, but I'm not sure.  It's not throwing me any errors, it just doesn't execute.  For example it wont even print  the "EDF".  Any suggestions?

```
    //Connection conn = null;
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/";
    String db = "db";
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String table = "order_queue";
    Connection conn = null;

    // Upload trade data to order_queue table
    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        System.out.print("EDF");
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+db,"root","");
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            String sql = "INSERT INTO " + table + " (name) VALUES("APPLE");
            st.executeUpdate(sql);
            conn.close();

        } catch (SQLException s) {
            s.printStackTrace();
            orderMessage = "ERROR: Problem executing order.  Please try again!";
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
        orderMessage = "ERROR: Problem connecting to OMS database.  Contact technical support or try again later."; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't print EDF you are having a problem loading the library. Did you add a reference to that library?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you catch Exception in your outer try catch block. So any other exception will be catch which you are not aware of and print out. Did you load the mysql connector java jar file in your CL classpath? (By the way, what's CL?)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is this line:

```
Class.forName(driver);
```

MySQL JDBC driver is not in your classpath. If you want to make sure this is the cause add one line to your code:

```
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
        orderMessage = "ERROR: Problem connecting to OMS database.  Contact technical support or try again later."; 
        cnfe.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this works in eclipse is probably because you've added it to your eclipse classpath for the project, so it automatically gets included in any main program you run.

For command line, make sure your classpath is setup right:

```
java -cp classes:/path/to/driver.jar MainClass
```

The important part here is the "-cp /path/to/driver.jar".  The "-cp" argument should include all the jars (separated by a : on *NIX and ; on windows) plus the directory where your classes are stored.

Alternatively, create a "lib" directory with your jar files somewhere and do this:

```
java -cp "classes:lib/*"  MainClass
```

When java sees a * like that it assumes you want to find all jar files in the specified directory.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Execution
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Execution
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)     any suggestions?

Comment: see my edit, you'll need to add your classes directory to the command line (i'm assuming it's called "classes")

Answer (score 0):

Try: java -cp /path/to/jdbc/driver.jar:. YourMainClass

Comment: Its giving me this Error message?      Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Execution
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Execution
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)